# I can not get my plugin to store values in my MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, minecraft

I am writing a plugin that will store values connected to a player in MySQL to be used by another server (Bungee cord) however still in testing so I am trying to save the Player's UUID, Name and DisplayName.

I followed a youtube tutorial as this is my first time dabbling in the dark arts. i have looked thru the video and have found nothing that sets aside my code from his. I even made the code create the table in the database because i was not sure what variables to use for UUID and the others

```
@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    createPlayer(player.getUniqueId(), player);
}

public boolean playerExists(UUID uuid) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = plugin.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + plugin.table + "WHERE UUID=?");
        statement.setString(1, uuid.toString());
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
        if(results.next()){
            plugin.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Player found");
            return true;
        }
        plugin.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player NOT found");
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
public void createPlayer(final UUID uuid, Player player) {
    try {
        Statement tableCreation = plugin.getConnection().createStatement();
        tableCreation.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + plugin.table + "(UUID varchar(36), PLAYER VARCHAR(16), DISPLAY_NAME VARCHAR(16))");
        PreparedStatement statement = plugin.getConnection()
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + plugin.table + "WHERE UUID=?");
        statement.setString(1, uuid.toString());
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(); // error here
        plugin.getLogger().info("Thinking...");
        results.next();
        if(!playerExists(uuid)){
            plugin.getLogger().info("Player dose not exist!");
            PreparedStatement insert = plugin.getConnection()
                    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + plugin.table + "(UUID,NAME,DISPLAY_NAME) VALUE (?,?,?)");
            insert.setString(1, uuid.toString());
            insert.setString(2, player.getName());
            insert.setString(3, player.getDisplayName());
            plugin.getLogger().info("Adding Player...");
            insert.executeUpdate();
            plugin.getLogger().info("Player Added");
            plugin.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Player Inserted");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know huge amount of code Sorry I marked where the code returns an error with // error here

Error in server log:
https://pastebin.com/3uQHmjqT

What I want is for the code to complete with out an error and for it to add player to my database table

For those who want to watch the video here you go:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HQ385ssa3Y - Part 1 setting it up to connect

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8hoBWnrqOU - Part 2 saving values (also putting connection values into a config)

Comment: You shouldn't be creating your table every time a player joins; it should be set up before you're doing any form of statements on it. PreparedStatements have placeholders (`?`) that you use instead of concatenating the input (`plugin.table`) to avoid injection, but in this case you should just write the table into the statement literally (I prefer saving `.sql` files and loading those). That all said, it _appears_ that the syntax error is in `UUID=?`. I'd put spaces between those (may not help) but I would also avoid naming your column `UUID`.

Comment: To add on; a database table's name is not something you should desire to make configurable

Comment: I created a table to make sure the table would be made correctly in the right place, I have removed it in my current code, and if Í space UUID=? to UUID = ? it gives:
`[19:32:17] [Server thread/WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= '(UUID here to long for me to post)`

Comment: and when I replace `plugin.table` with `?` and a `insert.setString(1, plugin.table);` it returns `[Server thread/WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''player_data' WHERE UUID = '(A player UUID)'' at line 1`

Comment: You can't substitute table names for some PreparedStatement implementations, including jdbc I believe. As for the error, it really looks like you're concatenating the UUID into the query. Are you sure there isn't an old version of the plugin on the server?

Comment: as soon as i make a change i replace the plugin whit the one i exported with new changes, and it is the ONLY plugin on the server. I am sure there is no old version of the plugin

Comment: Try naming the column something other than `UUID`, or, enclose the column reference in backticks: `'UUID'` but with ` (can't format it in stackoverflow comments). So `SET 'UUID' = ?` etc, but with `

Comment: Yes, that's the part I'm speaking about. My suspicion is that you've named your column as a reserved keyword, so any time you want to reference this column you will need those backticks. Otherwise it's akin to trying to set the value of a function to a string.

Comment: Using " ` " around UUID did not fix it nor did using " ' ", However whilst using " ' " it returns a error contain 'UUID' whilst using backticks it did not

Comment: Define "did not fix it", what was the error with backticks? It shouldn't work with single quotes around it; that denotes a string

Comment: did not fix it = same problem as without them, I also tried renaming the Entry or what it is called to PLAYERUUID instead of UUID with the same result as having simply UUID, it seems that the syntax is incorrect at ` = ?` and then to do `statement.setString(1, uuid.toString());`. as it keeps repeating the same error in the server console

Comment: Keep in mind you have multiple statements making that UUID reference, did you fix them all?

Comment: Yes, to my knowledge, however I did find that the guy making tutorials has posted his code on github and when taking his class it worked,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to MY problem was taking the code directly from the tutorial github.
https://github.com/DGIProject/UUIDSql/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/dgiproject/UUIDSql.java
i must have made a mistake somewhere but i could not find it. but that was my solution.

Edit 1: I looked thru both the github and mine and found a difference and when tested gave `MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near...` and it was a missing " " (space) between "plugin.table" and ""WHERE" it should have been "plugin.table + " WHERE". Now I am pretty sure i tested that but i guess not...